# Case Classes with Same Shape?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given two `case class`es:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
case class Bar(x: Int)
```

Using `shapeless`, how can I determine if `Foo` and `Bar` have the same "shape", i.e. `Int :: HNil` is `HList`?

Comment: `=:=` is not working?

Answer (score 5):

`A`, `B` have same shape if there exists a shape `S` such that `S` is the generic representation of both `A` and `B`. This translates directly into the following function:

```
trait SameShape[A, B]

object SameShape {
  implicit def instance[A, B, S]
    (implicit a: Generic.Aux[A, S], b: Generic.Aux[B, S]): SameShape[A, B] =
      new SameShape[A, B] {}
}
```

Comment: I guess return type doesn't even matter in this case.

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `def` there instead of `val`.

Comment: Also, `Generic` takes one type parameter. You probably wanted `Generic.Aux`

Answer (score 4):

For specific case classes you can just do:

```
  case class Foo(x: Int)
  case class Bar(x: Int)
  case class Baz(x: String)

  implicitly[Generic.Aux[Foo, Int :: HNil]]
  implicitly[Generic.Aux[Bar, Int :: HNil]]
  implicitly[Generic.Aux[Baz, String :: HNil]]
```

More general approach:

If you prefer to work with values you can create function:

```
  def test[A, B, L <: HList](a: A, b: B)(implicit
                                         gen1: Generic.Aux[A, L],
                                         gen2: Generic.Aux[B, L]): Int = 42

  val foo = Foo(1)
  val bar = Bar(2)
  val baz = Baz("a")

  test(foo, bar)  // compiles
//  test(foo, baz)  // doesn't compile
```

If you prefer to work with types you can create type class:

```
  trait SameShape[A, B]

  object SameShape {
    implicit def mkSameShape[A, B, L <: HList](implicit
                                               gen1: Generic.Aux[A, L],
                                               gen2: Generic.Aux[B, L]
                                               ): SameShape[A, B] =
      new SameShape[A, B] {}
  }

  implicitly[SameShape[Foo, Bar]]  // compiles
//  implicitly[SameShape[Foo, Baz]] // doesn't  compile
```